# Metabase H2 lost dat

Tags: docker, h2, restore, metabase

We use Metabase docker.

After a migration our Metabase H2 database file had wrong owner(root) and when we start Metabase, it worked but our new permissions and queries not saved on H2 file.

We can't find our data of that time (when file had wrong owner).where is it? is there any second file to store temp data?

Where this data stored and how can we restore our data?

Answer (score 0):

Kindly elaborate a bit more on what happened during the migration.
Did you copy the previous old H2 file to the new location before running Metabase?
It could be that metabase created a new H2 file when it could not find any hence creating the impression that all your data was Lost.
In this case copying the old H2 file to the new location should restore your Data.
It is however best practice to avoid using H2 files for storage as they don't scale well and can get corrupt.
Metabase supports RDBMS you can opt for either mysql or postgres to prevent loosing data in the future.
Metabase Documentation on the same:

https://www.metabase.com/docs/latest/installation-and-operation/configuring-application-database